# ios STPopup dismiss by tapping in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've used [STPopup library](https://github.com/kevin0571/STPopup) for created a popup in iOS app with Objective-c, so everything was fine.

Now I want dismiss popup by tapping in background but my code don't work and get error `backgroundViewDidTap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15780b7b0`

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)showPopupDaudit{
    STPopupController *popupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[POPViewController new]];
    [STPopupNavigationBar appearance].tintColor = MP_HEX_RGB(MAINCOLOR);;

    popupController.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    if (NSClassFromString(@"UIBlurEffect")) {
        UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
        popupController.backgroundView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    }
    [popupController.backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:popupController
                                                                                                 action:@selector(backgroundViewDidTap)]];
    [popupController presentInViewController:self];
}
```

**POPUPController.m**

```
- (IBAction)backgroundViewDidTap
{
    [self.popupController dismiss];
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: did u try changing IBAction to void ? Also put a breakpoint at [self.popupController dismiss]; and see if it gets hit before the crash occur!

Comment: Yes, I tried before but still crash, It doesn't run into this action, it seems to be failed at passing some thing between two controller

Comment: where did u declare self.popupController ?